# Debugging Access VBA Error

Tags: ms-access

I am building a form to add data to a table, and I have the whole code built but I keep getting this error and I have tried numerous ways to fix it but I cannot figure it out. The code is as follows:

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO CDData(Gender, EEOC, EmployeeID, EmployeeName, ReadinessLevel, Division, Center, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee, Justification, Changed) " & _
    " VALUES ('" & Me.cboGender & "','" & Me.cboEEOC & "','" & Me.txtID & "','" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.cboReady & "','" & Me.txtDivision & "','" & Me.txtCenter & "','" & Me.txtFeedback & "','" & _
    Me.txtDevelopment & "','" & Me.txtJustification & "','" & Me.cboChanged & "') "
```

And the error I keep getting is:

Run Time Error 3127
The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'EmployeeID'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.

Comment: What does your schema look like? That error is pretty intuitive/specific.

Comment: By `What does your schema look like?`, I mean - what are all of the exact field names in your `CDData` table? The error `unknown field name: 'EmployeeID'` means exactly what it says; that field name doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Those are my field names listed, exactly as they are typed in the code above

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your table definition in Access?

Comment: Something [like this](http://www.asiplease.net/computing/access/images/table_definition1.gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states your problem; 'Employee' is not in your table.  99.9% of the time, this is because the field name is misspelled.  Make sure there are no spaces **in** your field name, and no spaces **before** or **after** your field name in your actual table.  Once you have confirmed there are no spaces, I would suggest opening the table in Design mode and literally copy/paste the field name into your SQL statement.

Also, every one of those values is surrounded by single quotes, which will write to the table as text.  Make sure all those fields are actually text fields.  They probably are, but that's just something I noticed.

Comment: Thank you for making me feel/look foolish today :)